# Early 80's (70's) space based tv show

Tags: story-identification, tv, space

When I was a kid in the early 80's I remember watching a tv show about a big spaceship flying through space. I think it had few episodes, and the story revolved around the lives inside the ship.

I think I remember someone having a crossbow as a weapon.

It's very vague. Does this ring a bell to someone? I'm sorry for not having further details, but I was 4 or 5 when I saw it.

Edit: The answer is effectively a duplicate but not the question, as I didn't recall so many details as the other user.

Thanks

Comment: [Star Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(film)), maybe? Just a crude guess.

Comment: Was it a cartoon or live action?

Comment: It was live action. Aurochs got it right. It was the Starlost.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Could this be [The Starlost](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069638/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)? The series first aired in 1973, written by none other than Harlan Ellison and produced in Canada. The show was plagued by production issues throughout development, including the total failure of a newly devised filming technique 'magicam'. I'm currently struggling to find whether it was repeated much in the 80s, but this sounds like the show.

[image]

It was set on the generation ship named *Earthship Ark* searching for a new home planet, and one of the main characters Garth had a crossbow that he was rather fond of:

[image]

There is a good write up of the show [here](http://www.millionmonkeytheater.com/TheStarlost.html) which may jog your memory further.

Comment: Incredible Aurochs! That was precisely it! Thank you. I'm gonna try to find it to go though memory lane! I live in Portugal, so it was normal to only see this kind of show 10 or 15 years after the original run.

Comment: Weirdly, 10 hours after this Q&A was posted, googling "science fiction show crossbow" has The Starlost's Wikipedia page as the second result, even though the word "crossbow" doesn't appear on it. Was this a case of LMGTFY? Or is Google indexing this site constantly and intelligently enough that it knew to make that connection?

Comment: I, too, had vague childhood memories of this show, tracked it down, and re-watched the entire series a year or two ago.  Totally not worth it.  So, so bad.

Comment: @iabw - That's a case of google indexing because I tried that before to no help. You can see the top result is now this question. Google then proceeds to index Starlost related results.

Comment: It's not even intelligent I see now, just text matching. This question is also the top result for "science fiction show big spaceship flying through space". We need more science fiction with crossbows!